# Having errors in inheritance in Python

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, inheritance, constructor

I am trying to create a program with a real estate agent in mind. In this program, I am trying to cover the aspects of a home to rent with all the basic parameters in mind. However I am having some errors.

```
class Apartment:


    def __init__(self, aptNumber, address, bedrooms, baths):
        self._aptNumber = aptNumber
        self._address = address
        self._bedrooms = int(bedrooms)
        self._baths = float(baths)

    def _securiyDep(self):
        securityDeposit =   330(bedrooms)

    def _rent(self):
        rent = 250(bedrooms) + 150(bathrooms)+200

    def _renter(self):
        renter = "vacant"

    def setSecDep(self, deposit):
        self._deposit = 1000

    def setRent(self, rentMoney):
        self._rentMoney = 800

    def setRenter(self, renter):
        self._renter = "Vacant"

    def getData(self, Data):
        self._Data = Data

    def isVacant(self, vacancy):
        self._vacancy = "True" or "False"


        def __repr__(self):
            s = self._aptNumber+ " located at " + str(self._address) + " is rented at" + self._rent
            s+= " and has a security deposit = " + self._deposit + " and is = " + self._vacancy
            return s





# Test code for the Apartment Class
if __name__ == "__main__":
    apts = []
    apts.append(Apartment("10C", "107 E. Main", 3, 1.5))
    apts.append(Apartment("14B", "109 E. Main", 4, 2))
    apts.append(Apartment("13", "2207 W. Broadway", "5", "2.5"))

    for apt in apts:
        print(apt)
    print()

    apts[0].setRent("1245")
    apts[0].setRenter("Rocky Quartzite")
    apts[1].setSecDep("1000")
    apts[1].setRenter("Millie Milton")

    print(apts[0].getData())
    print()

    for apt in apts:
        if not apt.isVacant():
            print(apt)
    print()

    apts[0].setRenter("")
    print(apts[0])
```

I am having the error

```
    print(apts[0].getData())
<__main__.Apartment object at 0x0000000003124208>
TypeError: getData() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Data'
<__main__.Apartment object at 0x0000000003124240>
```

Can someone please help with the errors?

Comment: Unless it's mis-copied, it should be `def __init__(`, not `def _init__(`. It's probably using the default constructor, which doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: Also, statements like `rent = 250(bedrooms) + 150(bathrooms)+200` will throw other errors, you probably want to use `rent = 250 * bedrooms + 150 * bathrooms +200`
`

Comment: Thanks. That was a miscopy. Now i have the errors

    print(apts[0].getData())
<__main__.Apartment object at 0x0000000003124208>
TypeError: getData() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Data'
<__main__.Apartment object at 0x0000000003124240>

Comment: Your invocation of `getData()` doesn't match the signature.

Comment: Can you please make edits in my code directly?

Answer (score 0):

You call `getData` with no arguments on line 60: `print(apts[0].getData())`. In your definition it takes a parameter called `Data`.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. What do you want to put in `self._Data`?. As @wastl suggested, `getData` should be called `setData`, and you should use it to put whatever you want in `self._Data`. You can create another method `getData` which returns `self._Data`, and you can use it after you put something in `self._Data`.

Answer (score 0):

You define `getData` to take two arguments, namely `self` which is a refernce to the instance you are operating on, and which is "automatically" supplied, and the second argument is `Data`

```
def getData(self, Data):
    self._Data = Data
```

But when you call `getData` you don't supply the second argument `Data`

```
apts[0].getData()
```

Thus the interpreter tells you that 1 required argument is missing, which in your case is `Data`.

Since `getData` in your case actually sets the `Data` variable, it would be better to call it `setData`

If you want to retrive the `Data` variable the getter would have to looke something like this

```
def getData(self):
    return self._Data
```

Comment: But the program requires getData. If I change it to setData, it does not work.

Comment: see the last listing, this is how you would implement a getter for the `_Data` variable.

Comment: Now I have the error   return self._Data
AttributeError: 'Apartment' object has no attribute '_Data'

Comment: that is because you never actually set a value for data, you would either do this in the __init__ mehtod or in a setter mehtod. Maybe you could also specifiy what exactly `_Data` should be.